# Modify the navigationItem of a view controller which is presenting a modal view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm presenting a modal view controller in a `UISplitViewController` based app. I've swapped the default detail view for a `UINavigationController`.

In my `UINavigationController`, I've implemented some methods to show the "Master" button for the split view controller in the top left. The problem is that when the device orientation changes while the modal view is visible, the button does not disappear from the main view in my navigation controller.

What could be causing this issue?

**EDIT:**

I've moved the template logic for the button into  a subclass of UINavigationController. The problem is that when the visibleViewController presents a `modalViewcontroller`, *it* becomes the `visibleViewController`. So, my code won't correctly remove the button for some reason. Here's my code:

**Code:**

```
#pragma mark - Split view support

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController *)pc{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Menu", @"");

    //
    //  TODO: Handle cases where there is
    //  a modal view controller that is 
    //  being shown to the user.
    //


    [((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).navigationItem  setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];

    self.popoverController = pc;

}

// Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem{

    [self.visibleViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popoverController = nil;
}

//
//  Preserve navigation items across detail 
//  view loads in portrait mode.
//

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated{

    UIBarButtonItem *barItem = nil;

    if (self.visibleViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem != nil) {

        barItem = self.visibleViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    }

    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:animated];

    if (barItem != nil) {
        [self.visibleViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barItem];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the splitViewControllerDelegate methods called as expected? Put differently, if you create a split view project from the template, do your splitView methods get called at the same points in the rotation/viewing processes as the template project?

Comment: Yes, my problem is accessing the correct view controller. Apparently, I'm doing it wrong, since the modal view controller becomes the "`visibleViewController`" for some reason.

Comment: So the methods are being called at the same time and in the same order as a 'normal' split view project?

Comment: @RyanR - Yep, the code is all there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to use SplitViewController and display the button for the master view in a navigationItem. The UISplitViewControllerDelegate is specifically designed to work with a UIBarButtonItem, you'll probably have to implement a custom popover controller to get that to work.

Comment: I did, but the problem is that I'm not using a toolbar, but rather a UINavigationController and so the toolbar isn't there. I've modified the code to use the UINavigationItem of the visible view controller.

Comment: The same popover controller works, I'll try to edit my question for clarity.